# Spring MVC and JPA with restwebservice

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am getting this error in apache Tomcat logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataBaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
10-Oct-2015 00:41:01.266 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
10-Oct-2015 00:41:01.267 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1447)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:89)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1292)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1380)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:812)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.dao.JpaDao.save(JpaDao.java:69)
    at net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.dao.DataBaseInitializer.initDataBase(DataBaseInitializer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 55 more
10-Oct-2015 00:41:01.370 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2015-10-10 12:41:01,617] Artifact angular-rest-springsecurity:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2015-10-10 12:42:14,717] Artifact angular-rest-springsecurity:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
10-Oct-2015 00:42:43.433 INFO [Finalizer] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1321)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3246)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:1656)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4261)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.cleanup(ConnectionImpl.java:1248)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.finalize(ConnectionImpl.java:2655)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:101)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:32)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:178)
```

My web.xml file is this:

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>angular-rest-springsecurity</display-name>

    <!--
        Load Spring Context
     -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--
        Map the REST Servlet to /rest/
     -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--
        Apply Spring Security Filter to all Requests
     -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>**
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
    version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="examplePU">
        <class>net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.entity.NewsEntry</class>
        <class>net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.entity.User</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and Database Iniatilizer class:

```
package net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.dao;

import java.util.Date;

import net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.dao.newsentry.NewsEntryDao;
import net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.dao.user.UserDao;
import net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.entity.NewsEntry;
import net.dontdrinkandroot.example.angularrestspringsecurity.entity.User;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

/**
 * Initialize the database with some test entries.
 *
 * @author Philip W. Sorst <philip@sorst.net>
 */
public class DataBaseInitializer
{
    private NewsEntryDao newsEntryDao;
    private UserDao userDao;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    protected DataBaseInitializer()
    {
        /* Default constructor for reflection instantiation */
    }

    public DataBaseInitializer(UserDao userDao, NewsEntryDao newsEntryDao, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)
    {
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.newsEntryDao = newsEntryDao;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public void initDataBase()
    {
        User userUser = new User("user", this.passwordEncoder.encode("user"));
        userUser.addRole("user");
        this.userDao.save(userUser);

        User adminUser = new User("admin", this.passwordEncoder.encode("admin"));
        adminUser.addRole("user");
        adminUser.addRole("admin");
        this.userDao.save(adminUser);

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            NewsEntry newsEntry = new NewsEntry();
            newsEntry.setContent("This is example content " + i);
            newsEntry.setDate(new Date(timestamp));
            this.newsEntryDao.save(newsEntry);
            timestamp += 1000 * 60 * 60;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error was because dispatcher Servlet file. The Correct way of declare entitymanagerfactory was different. DatabaseInitilizer Class is used to intialize the database username and password in a encrypted format.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `passwordEncoder` being constructed and set in the `DataBaseInitializer`? It looks like its still null when `initDataBase()` is called here:

```
User userUser = new User("user", this.passwordEncoder.encode("user"));
```